# How to make my request synchronous in node.js?

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to create a request in node.js using 'request' module, but it works async. How does 'something2' shows up on console before 'something1' and how could I fix it? Is there any way to make it work synchronously?

```js
const request = require('request')

getSomething: function() {
  var options = { 
    method: 'GET',
    url: '...',
    headers: { 
      Authorization: 'Bearer ...'
    },
    json: true
  };

    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
        //code
        console.log('something1')
      }
    })
    console.log('something2')
},
```

Comment: Searching for this exact question will lead you to multiple solutions. The *best* solution, however, is to do it right, and wrap your head around async programming.

Comment: You can use `promise` -> `resolve` to execute `something2` after `something1` is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
getSomething: function() {
  var options = { 
    method: 'GET',
    url: '...',
    headers: { 
      Authorization: 'Bearer ...'
    },
    json: true
  };
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       request(options, (err, res, body) => {
           //code
           console.log('something1')
           resolve()
         }
       })
    })

    promise.then(() => {
       console.log('something2')
    })
},
```

I hope if works! 
Also take a look here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise) for more clarity